# Automatically connect to a WiFi which has a specific SSID (atleast first few characters) from an iPad app

Tags: ios, wifi, indoor-positioning-system, captivenetwork

When a user walks into a physical store, is it possible to verify if a particular WiFi SSID is available (may be searching with first few characters) and if yes, can we automatically connect to that WiFi programmatically? Getting consent from the user for first time is OK, but if user gives the consent, we should be able to automatically connect subsequent times. I know Captive framework can be used to get the connected WiFi details, but can we leverage that framework to implement the above requirement as well? Appreciate any quick inputs.

Comment: Currently, there is no way for the developer to access that type of system level APIs.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.  You can indeed only get the SSID once connected.